# mapping Json data and adding data attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a difficulty with mapping my my Json data. I would like to add data attr to each div with .name class. So as the result is like that:

```
<div class="name" data-key="sth"> sty</div>
```

Key can be got like that: ['streme'].key

here is my buggy JS:

```
function getExistingLinks() {
          $.post( "http://0.0.0.0:9292/api/links", function( data ) {
            var names = data.map(function (i) {
            return i['link'].name
            });
            var keys = data.map(function (i) {
            return i['link'].key
            });
            var container = document.querySelector(".link-names");
                names.forEach(function(name) {
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.innerHTML = name;
                    $('div').addClass("name");
                    // $('div').each( function(index) {
                           $('div')[index].data("key") = keys[index];
                       }
                    container.appendChild(div);
                });
       });  
      return false;   
    }
```

Comment: what does console.log( keys ); show..?

Comment: is hows 33 times Array[33] and in each of these 33 keys like that: 0: "p0E2bVUfq3zIRuUO9zY8X5ZbwAM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names.forEach(function(name,index) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = name;
  $(div).addClass("name");
  $(div).data("key") = keys[index];
});
```

You need to remove the quotes in the $() selector!

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined

Comment: @lipenco you need a loop around the index! The point is to remove the quotes and use `$(div)` instead of `$('div')`

Comment: hmm.. but  $(div).each(function( index ) {
                    $(div).data("key") = keys[index];
                 });   doesn't work: invalid left side of assignment

Comment: I have updated my answer. The issue in your original code is that `$('div')` gets all the div elements in the document, while what you really wanted was `$(div)` to grab the div you just created.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, may be try doing like:

```
var i = 0;
names.forEach(function(name) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = name;
    $('div').addClass("name");
    $('div').data("key", keys[i]);
    container.appendChild(div);
    i++;
});
```

Comment: $(div).data("key") = keys[i]; - I have an error: invalid left side of assignment

Comment: @lipenco see my updated answer.. do this:: $('div').data("key", keys[i]); instead

Answer (score 0):

the preferred method is to only add to the DOM once, as adding to the DOM will cause a redraw on each.

psuedo code as not sure what name represents in your innerHTML:

var divs = [];
for (var i, len = names.length; i < len; i++) {
    divs.push($(''+name+'').data("key", keys[i]));
}

$container.append(divs);

http://codepen.io/jsdev/pen/2866265243563efd79cf05a5b12202b3

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 $('.name').data('key') //will give you sth
```